# reputation change notification not visible

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

I think it's happening after the SO did their last maintenance yesterday.
I am not getting that green notification for reputation change neither that red one.

However the changes are being reflected in the overall reputation and and I can view the reputation change by going to the reputation tab on the profile page, but the notification is not being displayed.

Anyone else having the same issue?

Is it a bug or something?

**EDIT:**
 The comment notifications are being shown its just the reputation bar.

**EDIT 2:**

my meta reputation is also not updating on my SO accounts page.. It's still showing 113, but on meta it's 135..

Is it the same bug or a different one?

Comment: Yeah for me too and also showing same notifications.

Comment: Same here. Weird.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think its a duplicate because all those questions say that the reputation bar is stuck at a value, but i am saying that nothing is being shown on the reputation bar.

Comment: Same bug, something is broken and fixing it will fix all those symptoms. Might take one hour, might take several weeks. :/